# Alguém sabe o que eu tenho que fazer nessa table para que ela não fica torta assim?

Tags: php, html

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    foreach ($registro as $reg){

    echo "
<table class='centered' >
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Nome</th>
<th>Telefone</th>
<th>Email</th>
</tr>
</thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$reg['nome']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$reg['telefone']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$reg['email']."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O problema é que você está criando várias tabelas independentes (olhe o source da sua página para entender melhor).

Tire a estrutura da tabela do loop, assim terá várias linhas na mesma tabela:

```
<table class='centered' >
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Nome</th>
         <th>Telefone</th>
         <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
<?php
    foreach ($registro as $reg){
    echo "\t\t<tr>";
    echo "\t\t\t<td>".$reg['nome']."</td>";
    echo "\t\t\t<td>".$reg['telefone']."</td>";
    echo "\t\t\t<td>".$reg['email']."</td>";
    echo "\t\t</tr>";
}
?>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Note que eu acrescentei alguns `\t` nos `echo` para indentar, você não precisa fazer isto, e se fizer, ponha o quanto for necessário para alinhar certinho com o resto do HTML (para ajudar você a entender). O `\t` é o caractere de tabulação, pode trocar por espaços em branco.

Comment: deu tudo certinho aqui, muito obrigada pela sua valiosa ajuda